# Stored procedure executing based on parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetValues
    @Value varchar(50) = ‘ALL’,
    @date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Value <> 'ALL'
    BEGIN
        SELECT Col1, Col2 
        INTO #TempTable
        FROM NewTable
        WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datecol, @date) = 0
          AND detail = @Value
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT col1, Col2 
        INTO #TempTable
        FROM NewTable
        WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datecol, @date) = 0 
    END
    
    ……../* Use the #TempTable and calculate */

END
```

I am getting an error

> There is already a table named #TempTable in the database

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest combining these into a single statement:

```
select Col1, Col2 into #TempTable
from NewTable
where datediff(day, datecol, @date) = 0 and
      (detail = @Value or @Value = 'All')
```

If you want this optimized for each parameter values, then you can add `option (recompile)`.

However, if performance is a concern, then I would suggest writing the logic as:

```
where datecol >= @date and
      datecol < dateadd(day, 1, @date) and
      (detail = @Value or @Value = 'All')
```

or:

```
where convert(date, datecol) = @date 
      (detail = @Value or @Value = 'All')
```

Either of these can take advantage of an index on `(datecol)`.

Comment: - the detail column doesn't have 'ALL' in it.

Comment: @kalls . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.

Comment: I cannot do (detail =@value or @value = 'All') because detail column doesn't have 'ALL' in it. I am using 'ALL' to exclude the condition in query (not using where clause)

Comment: @kalls . . . That logic is not assuming that `detail` has `'All'`.  It is only comparing `@value`.

Answer (score 0):

To get going quick you could add the statement `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable` at the beginning of the proc.  The likely reason the table exists is the proc was interrupted before the table was dropped when it fell out of scope.  It's quick, simple, and costless to make it D.I.E. (drop if exists) in the code.  Something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetValues
    @Value varchar(50) = ‘ALL’,
    @date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
         DROP TABLE #TempTable;

    IF @Value <> 'ALL'
    BEGIN
        SELECT Col1, Col2 
        INTO #TempTable
        FROM NewTable
        WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datecol, @date) = 0
          AND detail = @Value
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT col1, Col2 
        INTO #TempTable
        FROM NewTable
        WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datecol, @date) = 0 
    END
    
    ……../* Use the #TempTable and calculate */

END
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not using SQL Server 2016 and DROP TABLE IF EXISTS is available from SQL Server 2016. Thank you.

Comment: Alternately, for pre-2016, you could check by object_id and drop if exists.